# Why the set of plugins can be different between Safari and WebView component?

Tags: macos, safari, webview

Our Mac desktop application embeds WebView component from WebKit framework.
Inside WebView we host Flash Player where we render UI.

As far as I know, Safari uses WebKit/WebView to display the content.

We were expecting Safari to host the same WebView component our application hosts.
In other words, if Flash plugin is installed in Safari, than Flash will be available in our WebView.

Unfortunately this appeared to be wrong for one of our users.

On his Mac, Flash runs flawlessly in Safari, but our WebView displays "Missing Plugin" message in place of Flash Player.

Mac OS X 10.5.8

Why this can happen?

Is it possible Safari to use a different WebView (or WebView settings) than our application is using?

I would appreciate any advice that would help us to find the source of the problem.

I have asked the user to run a small script that prints a set of plugins installed for Safari and for our WebView.
There are around 20 plugins installed in Safari, including Flash Player.
But there are only 3 plugins installed for our WebView.
Here they are:

```
Java Plug-In 2 for NPAPI Browsers
Switchable Java Plug-In for WebKit
RealPlayer Plugin.plugin
```

Pasha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible Safari to use a different WebView (or WebView settings) than our application is using?

Yes, very much so. A WebView is simply a class, and Safari uses one instance of such a class, which doesn't get modified for a plug-in. The Flash plug-in is installed for the browser (as in, Safari keeps track of where it is installed and looks for it as necessary). Cocoa's WebView doesn't get modified whenever a plug-in is installed—that could lead to all sorts of issues.

Comment: Not sure what RealPlayer is doing there, but the Java plug-ins are integrated at a lower level and so Cocoa's WebView gets to use them.

Comment: Quite honestly, I'd recommend that you move away from Flash—HTML5 is a much better alternative, is much better supported (as evidenced by this question), and won't tax the system as much. As a consumer myself, I know I'll be turned away from any service if it makes use of Flash—I have Flash blockers installed in all my browsers. But that's just my personal opinion. :)